# How to pass tuple in controller of mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am using
@model Tuple <*xx.Models.xyz, xx.Models.BL.abc*>
this model in my view page 
I want this Both class in controller 
How will i retrieve the value of both the class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `viewbag.xxx`

example

```
@foreach ( var item in viewbag.xxx)
{
  your code
}
```

Comment: No No I am asking that
I am using tuple in view page and after submiting the view 
i need the value of both the class in controller page 
How?

Comment: user1006544
try

@using (Html.BeginForm("", ""})) 

sblom: ya